# workflow and time based workflow help

Tags: workflow, formula, datetime, time-dependent-workflow

Is there a way to assign a timebased workflow for the following?
I have 2 fields, reminder__c, and registration_date__c. If my reminder__c is blank for 14days or more after
my registration_date__c, i would like to assign a task to the user. Subject of the task will be "Register for your course". Is this possible through workflow/time-based workflow?

reminder__c is under custom object 'Student'. and registration_date__c is under custom object 'School'. Student have a lookup to School.

Thank you.

[image]

I started on workflow, but is stuck as I am not sure how the logic would work...

Comment: Hi R.Wolf, welcome to SFSE. You cropped the actual error message out of your screenshot. Please **[edit]** your post to include the error message text.

Comment: I have updated the image

Answer (score 1):

That's not how workflow rules or process builder flows work. You need to start from the basic criteria, then you add the time component later.

In this case, the condition is Reminder__c is blank/null/empty. That is what will trigger the process/workflow.

In the next step, you specify the time. The basic idea would be "14 days after the registration date, create a new task."

The catch is, you can't reference parent fields directly to set the time, so you'll need to create a formula for that:

```
School_Registration_Date__c (Date):

School__r.Registration_Date__c
```

Once you do that, it's a simple matter of setting up the process/workflow.

You can use the standard "criteria is met" option: "Reminder equals " (nothing, a blank value). You could also choose to use a formula, but that's overkill.

Once you save the workflow rule, on the next step, add a time trigger that reads "14 days after School Registration Date," then create the appropriate workflow task.

In the Process Builder, you can also build this same flow, and the steps are nearly identical, though some of the terminology is different.

Comment: so i did create a workflow based on formula. ISBLANK( reminder__C)= true and have set a time trigger that runs after 14 days. but where do i reference the formula School_Registration_Date__c ? do i have to create 2 separate flows?

Comment: @R.Wolf The time trigger is where you reference it. It should read "14 Days After Student: School Registration Date"

Comment: @sfcdox oh my. I messed up again. I think I got it now. I created a new formula field and have set the trigger reference to it. Thank you.

Comment: @R.Wolf You're welcome!